# Run task few seconds/minutes/hours later after a call

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, task, scheduled-tasks

Does Spring Boot have something that allows to run a task several minutes later after a call?

Update:
Found that Spring Boot has `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`. That allows to implement one time task execution with a time delay. See the answer below

Comment: This seems like a fit for an event-driven approach. When call A is made, then Event A created and bean B is notified to begin processing. In the Bean B processes, make the first step a wait.  You could probably do this with Spring Reactor, or usage of the Java Observable/Observer API

Comment: *"Does **Spring** Boot have something that allows to run a **task**"* → Web search for [`spring task`](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+task) → [Spring Framework Documentation - Integration - 7. Task Execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)

Comment: @Lenar Now I remember the feeling of lazy people asking questions because it's easier than doing your own research. --- *"Or there is only the TimerTask/Timer approach?"* Obviously not, since a minimal amount of research would say otherwise. If you has just done a super simple web search, you'd know that, and may have been able to ask a much *better* question, that might actually be worth answering. I didn't deem this question that good, which is why I *commented*, rather than answered, and since I don't receive rep for comments, how is this "jerking off"?

Comment: @Lenar Actually, I have asked 1 question, answered more than 3000 questions, and left more than 14000 comments. Most comments because of bad questions (of which there are too many), but also quiet a few comments to suggest improvements to answers by other people. --- Also note that down-voting cost the voter rep, so if we were all *"just jerking off on stats/reputation"*, you'd never get a down-vote on here. We actually care about the quality of this site, which is *why* we leave comments to get better questions, and hence build a useful Q&A repository.

Comment: @Michael Peacock
Thank you for ideas, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to define a Bean

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler getScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setPoolSize(10);
    return scheduler;
}
```

The task that needs to be executed

```
public class WakeUpCallTask implements Runnable {

    private String parameter1;

    private String parameter2;

    public WakeUpCallTask(String parameter1, String parameter2) {
        super();
        this.parameter1= parameter1;
        this.parameter2= parameter2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code that should be executed
    }

}
```

Endpoint example - scheduling a task in 10000ms

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

@PostMapping(value = "/wake-me-up", consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void scheduleCall(@RequestBody WakeMeUpRequest request) {
    scheduler.schedule(
            new WakeUpCallTask(request.getParameter1(), request.getParameter2()),
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000));
}
```